# BUG? deleting occurrence with ews managed api deletes entire series

Tags: calendar, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, managed

After binding to an occurrence as an appointment item using it's occurrence index I delete it.
This used to work fine but now the entire series is gone from the calendar. (o365)

When I do a quick watch in debugger right after delete on the master item (objOutput) that is still referenced I see that most properties give an exception, though not all.

Has there been a change in Excahnge server? Can I no longer delete instances of a series?

Here is the watch:
objOutput   {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment}   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment

- ```
    AdjacentMeetingCount    'objOutput.AdjacentMeetingCount' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AdjacentMeetings    'objOutput.AdjacentMeetings' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemCollection(Of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment) {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AllowNewTimeProposal    'objOutput.AllowNewTimeProposal' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AllowedResponseActions  'objOutput.AllowedResponseActions' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ResponseActions {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AppointmentReplyTime    'objOutput.AppointmentReplyTime' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AppointmentSequenceNumber   'objOutput.AppointmentSequenceNumber' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AppointmentState    'objOutput.AppointmentState' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    AppointmentType 'objOutput.AppointmentType' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AppointmentType {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ArchiveTag  'objOutput.ArchiveTag' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ArchiveTag {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Attachments {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttachmentCollection}  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttachmentCollection
  ```
- ```
    Body    'objOutput.Body' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MessageBody {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Categories  {}  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StringList
  ```
- ```
    ConferenceType  'objOutput.ConferenceType' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ConflictingMeetingCount 'objOutput.ConflictingMeetingCount' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ConflictingMeetings 'objOutput.ConflictingMeetings' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemCollection(Of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment) {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ConversationId  'objOutput.ConversationId' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConversationId {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Culture 'objOutput.Culture' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    DateTimeCreated 'objOutput.DateTimeCreated' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    DateTimeReceived    'objOutput.DateTimeReceived' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    DateTimeSent    'objOutput.DateTimeSent' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
    DeletedOccurrences  Nothing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeletedOccurrenceInfoCollection
  ```
- ```
    DisplayCc   'objOutput.DisplayCc' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    DisplayTo   'objOutput.DisplayTo' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Duration    'objOutput.Duration' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    System.TimeSpan {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    EffectiveRights 'objOutput.EffectiveRights' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EffectiveRights {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    [End]   'objOutput.[End]' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    EndTimeZone 'objOutput.EndTimeZone' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' System.TimeZoneInfo {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    EnhancedLocation    'objOutput.EnhancedLocation' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EnhancedLocation {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    EntityExtractionResult  'objOutput.EntityExtractionResult' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EntityExtractionResult {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```

- ```
    ExtendedProperties  {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyCollection}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyCollection
    Count   0   Integer
  ```

- ```
    Non-Public members
  ```
- ```
    Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
  ```

- ```
    FirstOccurrence {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OccurrenceInfo}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OccurrenceInfo
    [End]   #2/8/2024 09:30:00 AM#  Date
  ```

- ```
    ItemId  {AQIBUQAICADcKDjks0AARgAAAk34SzcD4/tOjy9YoyDQBdQHAAjFPRy+0CFKlPGWbPbV3gEAAAMWAAAACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQABXgDzUQAAABAuAAADTfhLNwPj+06PL1ijINAF1AEACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQAAAxYAAAA=}  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId
    OriginalStart   #2/8/2024 09:00:00 AM#  Date
    Start   #2/8/2024 09:00:00 AM#  Date
  ```
- ```
    Non-Public members
  ```
- ```
    Flag    'objOutput.Flag' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Flag {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    HasAttachments  'objOutput.HasAttachments' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ICalDateTimeStamp   'objOutput.ICalDateTimeStamp' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Date? {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ICalRecurrenceId    'objOutput.ICalRecurrenceId' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Date? {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ICalUid 'objOutput.ICalUid' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IconIndex   'objOutput.IconIndex' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IconIndex {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```

- ```
    Id  {AQIARgAAA034SzcD4/tOjy9YoyDQBdQHAAjFPRy+0CFKlPGWbPbV3gEAAAMWAAAACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQABXgDzUQAAAC4AAANN+Es3A+P7To8vWKMg0AXUAQAIxT0cvtAhSpTxlmz21d4BAAADFgAAAA==}  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId
    ChangeKey   "DwAAABYAAAAIxT0cvtAhSpTxlmz21d4BAAFeUfyx"  String
    UniqueId    "AQIARgAAA034SzcD4/tOjy9YoyDQBdQHAAjFPRy+0CFKlPGWbPbV3gEAAAMWAAAACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQABXgDzUQAAAC4AAANN+Es3A+P7To8vWKMg0AXUAQAIxT0cvtAhSpTxlmz21d4BAAADFgAAAA=="  String
  ```

- ```
    Non-Public members
  ```
- ```
    Importance  'objOutput.Importance' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Importance {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    InReplyTo   'objOutput.InReplyTo' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    InstanceKey 'objOutput.InstanceKey' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Byte() {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    InternetMessageHeaders  'objOutput.InternetMessageHeaders' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.InternetMessageHeaderCollection {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsAllDayEvent   'objOutput.IsAllDayEvent' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsAssociated    'objOutput.IsAssociated' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
    IsAttachment    False   Boolean
  ```
- ```
    IsCancelled 'objOutput.IsCancelled' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
    IsDirty False   Boolean
  ```
- ```
    IsDraft 'objOutput.IsDraft' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsFromMe    'objOutput.IsFromMe' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsMeeting   'objOutput.IsMeeting' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
    IsNew   False   Boolean
  ```
- ```
    IsOnlineMeeting 'objOutput.IsOnlineMeeting' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsRecurring 'objOutput.IsRecurring' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsReminderSet   'objOutput.IsReminderSet' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsResend    'objOutput.IsResend' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsResponseRequested 'objOutput.IsResponseRequested' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsSubmitted 'objOutput.IsSubmitted' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    IsUnmodified    'objOutput.IsUnmodified' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ItemClass   'objOutput.ItemClass' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    JoinOnlineMeetingUrl    'objOutput.JoinOnlineMeetingUrl' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    LastModifiedName    'objOutput.LastModifiedName' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    LastModifiedTime    'objOutput.LastModifiedTime' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```

- ```
    LastOccurrence  {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OccurrenceInfo}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OccurrenceInfo
    [End]   #8/1/2024 09:30:00 AM#  Date
  ```

- ```
    ItemId  {AQIBUQAICADcsbzi/YAARgAAAk34SzcD4/tOjy9YoyDQBdQHAAjFPRy+0CFKlPGWbPbV3gEAAAMWAAAACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQABXgDzUQAAABAuAAADTfhLNwPj+06PL1ijINAF1AEACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQAAAxYAAAA=}  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId
    OriginalStart   #8/1/2024 09:00:00 AM#  Date
    Start   #8/1/2024 09:00:00 AM#  Date
  ```
- ```
    Non-Public members
  ```
- ```
    LegacyFreeBusyStatus    'objOutput.LegacyFreeBusyStatus' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LegacyFreeBusyStatus {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Location    'objOutput.Location' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    MeetingRequestWasSent   'objOutput.MeetingRequestWasSent' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Boolean {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    MeetingWorkspaceUrl 'objOutput.MeetingWorkspaceUrl' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    MimeContent 'objOutput.MimeContent' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MimeContent {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ModifiedOccurrences 'objOutput.ModifiedOccurrences' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OccurrenceInfoCollection {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    MyResponseType  'objOutput.MyResponseType' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MeetingResponseType {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    NetShowUrl  'objOutput.NetShowUrl' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    NormalizedBody  'objOutput.NormalizedBody' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.NormalizedBody {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    OnlineMeetingSettings   'objOutput.OnlineMeetingSettings' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OnlineMeetingSettings {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    OptionalAttendees   {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttendeeCollection}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttendeeCollection
  ```
- ```
    Organizer   'objOutput.Organizer' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    OriginalStart   'objOutput.OriginalStart' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ParentFolderId  'objOutput.ParentFolderId' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    PolicyTag   'objOutput.PolicyTag' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PolicyTag {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Preview 'objOutput.Preview' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Recurrence  'objOutput.Recurrence' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ReminderDueBy   'objOutput.ReminderDueBy' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    ReminderMinutesBeforeStart  'objOutput.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```

- ```
    RequiredAttendees   {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttendeeCollection}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttendeeCollection
    Count   0   Integer
  ```

- ```
    Non-Public members
  ```
- ```
    Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
  ```
- ```
    Resources   {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttendeeCollection}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttendeeCollection
  ```
- ```
    RetentionDate   'objOutput.RetentionDate' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Date? {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Schema  {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AppointmentSchema} Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectSchema {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AppointmentSchema}
  ```
- ```
    Sensitivity 'objOutput.Sensitivity' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Sensitivity {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Service {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService}   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
  ```
- ```
    Size    'objOutput.Size' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Integer {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Start   'objOutput.Start' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   Date {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    StartTimeZone   'objOutput.StartTimeZone' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'   System.TimeZoneInfo {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    StoreEntryId    'objOutput.StoreEntryId' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Byte() {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    Subject 'objOutput.Subject' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException' String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    TextBody    'objOutput.TextBody' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.TextBody {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    TimeZone    'objOutput.TimeZone' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    UniqueBody  'objOutput.UniqueBody' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.UniqueBody {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    WebClientEditFormQueryString    'objOutput.WebClientEditFormQueryString' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    WebClientReadFormQueryString    'objOutput.WebClientReadFormQueryString' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'    String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```
- ```
    [When]  'objOutput.[When]' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException'  String {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException}
  ```

- ```
    Non-Public members      
    DefaultAffectedTaskOccurrences  Nothing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AffectedTaskOccurrence?
    DefaultSendCancellationsMode    SendToAllAndSaveCopy {2}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendCancellationsMode?
    DefaultSendInvitationsMode  SendToAllAndSaveCopy {2}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsMode?
    DefaultSendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode   SendToAllAndSaveCopy {3}    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode?
    OnChange    Nothing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectChangedDelegate
    ParentAttachment    Nothing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemAttachment
  ```

- ```
    PropertyBag {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag}   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag
  ```
- ```
    RootItemId  {AQIARgAAA034SzcD4/tOjy9YoyDQBdQHAAjFPRy+0CFKlPGWbPbV3gEAAAMWAAAACMU9HL7QIUqU8ZZs9tXeAQABXgDzUQAAAC4AAANN+Es3A+P7To8vWKMg0AXUAQAIxT0cvtAhSpTxlmz21d4BAAADFgAAAA==}  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId
    lockObject  {Object}    Object
    parentAttachment    Nothing Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemAttachment
  ```
- ```
    propertyBag {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag}   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag
  ```
- ```
    service {Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService}   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
    xmlElementName  "CalendarItem"  String
  ```

I expected the instance to be deleted from objoutput and not the whole series